# Dynamically change button background color in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, button

I have 3 buttons in my .Net app and I would like to know how I can perform the below code dynamically.

Public Class frmTC

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Button1.BackColor = Color.Red
    Button2.BackColor = Color.Yellow
    Button3.BackColor = Color.Yellow
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Button1.BackColor = Color.Yellow
    Button2.BackColor = Color.Red
    Button3.BackColor = Color.Yellow
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Button1.BackColor = Color.Yellow
    Button2.BackColor = Color.Yellow
    Button3.BackColor = Color.Red
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: What do you mean by Dynamically ? What do you exactly want to do ? What are your efforts ?

Comment: like if statement,because I want to put my codes in module and call it for each button. Do you have any Idea?

Comment: Then why are you using Buttons ? Just call the logic on if statement.

Comment: Or if you want to call specific button click event, you can use `PerformClick()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
   Dim btn As Button = CType(sender, Button)
   SetColor(btn)
End Sub

Private Sub SetColor(Button button)
    Button1.BackColor = Color.Yellow
    Button2.BackColor = Color.Yellow
    Button3.BackColor = Color.Yellow
    button.BackColor =Color.Red
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call Above button clicks, you can use `PerformClick()` method to call Events.

For More information, please visit [**Here**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.performclick(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2)

Answer (score 0):

You can handle all the events in one handler;

```
Private Sub Buttons_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click, Button2.Click, Button3.Click 

select Case sender.ToString

  Case "Button1"
    Button1.BackColor = Color.Red
    Button2.BackColor = Color.Yellow
    Button3.BackColor = Color.Yellow

  Case "Button2"
    Button1.BackColor = Color.Yellow
    Button2.BackColor = Color.Red
    Button3.BackColor = Color.Yellow

  Case "Button3"
    Button1.BackColor = Color.Yellow
    Button2.BackColor = Color.Yellow
    Button3.BackColor = Color.Red

End Sub
```

Sorry I don't have the platform to test it, but I guess it might guide you in the right direction.